# Issues with passing context

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom list adaptor for a listview within an android application

i have just implimented an extention of the Applicaion class in order to store some global variables

when setting or getting the variable i have to pass context

below is the getView function of the CustomListView

im attempting to set a global variable (within the onClickListener) by passing with it the same context that i use successfully on an intent moments later.

However i receive the following error

```
04-08 22:11:17.534  21919-21919/com.example.alex.camerascan4 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alex.camerascan4, PID: 21919
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.alex.camerascan4.CategoryActivity cannot be cast to com.example.alex.camerascan4.MyApplication
            at com.example.alex.camerascan4.CustomListView$1.onClick(CustomListView.java:74)
```

ive also tried using the view.getContext method for the available views, but its still not working

```
 public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        final View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_category_listitem, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.tv.setText(mDataset.get(position));
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+mDataset.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ((MyApplication) context).setRequestID(mDatamap.get(position));

                //  login success and move to main Activity here.
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DocumentActivity.class);

                ((Activity) context).startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to access `MyApplication` object would be like this -

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static MyApplication context = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
   }
}
```

Now wherever you want to call method of `MyApplication` class you can directly call like this -

```
MyApplication.context.setRequestID(mDatamap.get(position));
```

You don't have to typecast any context to `Application` context in order to use it. You can use simply as above anywhere in your application.

Comment: Holding onto a context statically is an anti-pattern that results in memory leaks. Don't do this.